# Which print calls in C do NOT ever call malloc() under the hood?

Tags: c, printing, printf

I'm implementing my own `fast_malloc()` to replace `malloc()`. I need debugging prints inside it. Are there any print calls which are guaranteed to NOT ever call `malloc()`, or do I need to create my own, safe versions?

Previously, [I had accidentally caused infinite recursion by having my `malloc()` call `printf()`, which then calls `malloc()`, which then calls `printf()`...forever.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68188903/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-for-no-such-file-or-directory-for-libiop-h)

If I need to create my own safe versions which use a fixed-size static array under the hood as the buffer to format into, that's all I need to know. I can do that.

How about `puts()` or `putc()`? They should be safe, no?

I'm on Linux Ubuntu 20.04. Ideally, whatever I do will be cross-platform-compliant, but I suppose I can customize if I need to for low-level system calls.

---

### Related:

1. Related, but not a duplicate since it is specific to `snprintf()`: [snprintf that calls malloc, or snprintf that does not call malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803808/snprintf-that-calls-malloc-or-snprintf-that-does-not-call-malloc)
2. [Does fprintf use malloc() under the hood?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743034/does-fprintf-use-malloc-under-the-hood)

Comment: `write(STDOUT_FILENO, str, strlen(str))`

Comment: @kaylum, looks like that is this Linux system call, no? https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html. Probably not cross-platform-compliant?

Comment: I doubt that `puts` and `putc` call `malloc`. But anyway using `write` to stdout for sure doesn't and it's pretty platform independant.

Comment: You probably have to use only system call. Under Windows, it is [WriteFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile).

Comment: If you can add code to your project: [No-malloc one-file printf() with optional floating point support](https://www.reddit.com/r/embedded/comments/3mbn47/nomalloc_onefile_printf_with_optional_floating/)

Comment: @kaylum, side note: consider making your comments answers next time. Your comment above [as well as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68171246/in-gcc-is-there-any-way-to-dynamically-add-a-function-call-to-the-start-of-main#comment120485051_68171246) were both the answers it looks like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are there any print calls which are guaranteed to NOT ever call malloc()

*Usually* you can call `fprintf(stderr, ...)`. This is because `stderr` is unbuffered by default.

However, this may not work from within `malloc` early in the process lifetime, before the rest of `libc` has initialized itself.

Your best bet is to use `write(2)`.

Answer (score 1):

### Here is a `safe_printf()` function which *never* calls `malloc()`!

I ended up writing a `safe_printf()` function which never calls `malloc()`, in case anyone ever needs it. I've tested it, and it works fine inside `malloc()`. It uses the `write()` system call (not std C) to write the chars to stdout.

Here it is:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#ifdef DEBUG
    /// Debug printf function.
    /// See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1941336/4561887
    #define DEBUG_PRINTF(...) safe_printf("DEBUG: "__VA_ARGS__)

    #define DEBUG_ASSERT(test_condition) assert(test_condition)
#else
    #define DEBUG_PRINTF(...) \
        do                    \
        {                     \
        } while (0)

    #define DEBUG_ASSERT(test_condition) \
        do                               \
        {                                \
        } while (0)
#endif

/// \brief      A **safe** version of `printf()`, meaning it NEVER calls `malloc()`, unlike
///             `printf()`, which may.
/// \details    This is achieved by using a fixed-size buffer to format strings into. You may see
///             a much simpler implementation from the Hacettepe University in Turkey, here, as a
///             basic example:
///             https://web.cs.hacettepe.edu.tr/~bbm341/codes/ecf/signals/safe_printf.c
#define SAFE_PRINTF_BUF_SIZE 2048
__attribute__((__format__(printf, 1, 2)))
int safe_printf(const char *format, ...)
{
    static char buf[SAFE_PRINTF_BUF_SIZE];
    // number of chars successfully written to `buf` and which we need to print
    int chars_to_print = 0;

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    int char_count_or_error = vsnprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), format, args);
    va_end(args);

    DEBUG_ASSERT(char_count_or_error >= 0); // if fails: ENCODING ERROR
    DEBUG_ASSERT(char_count_or_error < (int)sizeof(buf)); // if fails: BUFFER IS TOO SMALL

    if (char_count_or_error < 0)
    {
        // ERROR: ENCODING ERROR
        return char_count_or_error;
    }
    else if (char_count_or_error >= (int)sizeof(buf))
    {
        // ERROR: BUFFER IS TOO SMALL to write the full character sequence!
        chars_to_print = sizeof(buf) - 1;
        char_count_or_error = -char_count_or_error; // make negative to show it was an error
    }
    else // char_count_or_error >= 0 && char_count_or_error < sizeof(buf)
    {
        // No error
        chars_to_print = char_count_or_error;
    }

    ssize_t num_bytes_written = write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, chars_to_print);
    DEBUG_ASSERT(num_bytes_written >= 0); // If fails: failure to write

    // Return BUFFER IS TOO SMALL error
    if (char_count_or_error < 0)
    {
        return char_count_or_error;
    }

    return num_bytes_written;
}
```

### References:

1. The [comment by @kaylum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68189631/which-print-calls-in-c-do-not-ever-call-malloc-under-the-hood#comment120516288_68189631):

   > ```
   > write(STDOUT_FILENO, str, strlen(str))
   > ```
2. The [answer by @Employed Russian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68189738/4561887)
3. A much simpler implementation from the Hacettepe University in Turkey, here, as a basic example: [https://web.cs.hacettepe.edu.tr/~bbm341/codes/ecf/signals/safe_printf.c](https://web.cs.hacettepe.edu.tr/%7Ebbm341/codes/ecf/signals/safe_printf.c)
4. Linux `write(2)` reference page: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html
5. The `vsnprintf()` usage example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vsnprintf/
6. `stdarg.h` reference: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/

### See also:

1. [my answer: this is where I identified the infinite recursion problem where `printf()` calls `malloc()`, which calls `printf()`, repeatedly; that is what motivated me to write the `safe_printf()` implementation above!] ["Segmentation fault (core dumped)" for: "No such file or directory" for libioP.h, printf-parse.h, vfprintf-internal.c, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68188903/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-for-no-such-file-or-directory-for-libiop-h/68201136#68201136)

Comment: This is valid only if `vsnprintf` doesn't call `malloc` either. Which as far as I know is implementation dependent.